# materialize-css Uncaught TypeError: Vel is not a function

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack, materialize

I'm using webpack as my bundler/loader and I can load materialize css in fine (js/css), but when I try to use the toast, it says

`Uncaught TypeError: Vel is not a function`

I am including the library in the main `index.js` file by:

`import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.css'
import 'materialize-css/bin/materialize.js'`

Does anyone know why this could be happening? Looking at the bundled source, the js for materialize is there.

Comment: Same issue for me... Have you found the cause ?

Answer (score 3):

Had a same problem & came up with somewhat simpler solution:
Only 2 things are needed to be done:

**First:** Import following in you root module like `app.js`

```
//given you have installed materialize-css with npm/yarn

import "materialize-css";
import 'materialize-css/js/toasts';
```

**Second:** if webpack, set following Plugin or get the velocity.min.js as global variable just like you would use jquery:

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "$": "jquery",
    "jQuery': "jquery",
    "Vel": "materialize-css/js/velocity.min.js"
  }),
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to use materialize-css with webpack and have also run into this issue (albeit not for the same reason). Materialize isn't really built with a module loader in mind, and use global variables. They also bundle dependencies into their script directly in a way you might not want in a webpack-workflow.

I have a setup not exactly the same as you but I'll share it anyways, hoping it will help, my webpack+materialize works like this in a file i've created;

```
/**
 * custom-materialize.js
 */

// a scss file where we include the parts I use.
require('./custom-materialize.scss');

/**
 * materialize script includes
 * we don't use all the plugins so no need to
 * include them in our package.
 */
require('materialize-css/js/initial');
require('materialize-css/js/jquery.easing.1.3');
require('materialize-css/js/animation');
// note: we take these from npm instead.
//require('materialize-css/js/velocity.min');
//require('materialize-css/js/hammer.min');
//require('materialize-css/js/jquery.hammer');
require('materialize-css/js/global');
//require('materialize-css/js/collapsible');
require('materialize-css/js/dropdown');
```

Then just install Velocity from npm `npm install velocity-animate`
and point the global `Vel` materialize use to that package instead in webpack.

```
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    '$': 'jquery',
    'jQuery': 'jquery',
    'Vel': 'velocity-animate'
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to import css and js Files separately in your index.html 
you must not import css file in index.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the uglifyJsPlugin is like this.

```
 new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({sourceMap: true, mangle: false})
```

`mangle` property should be false so that the variable names of your source file doesn't change when you minify.